# Duplicate number check doesn't always work

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, random

I have a function `getNormalList()` that must return a list with 3 random integers 0-5, not all the same. It's not working like I want it to work. Sometimes, despite the check, it outputs the same 3 numbers.

```
public class SpinResultGenerator {

    public ArrayList<Integer> getNormalList() {
        ArrayList<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Random r = new Random();
        int Low = 0;
        int High = 6;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            int number = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
            integerList.add(number);
        }
        if (integerList.get(0) == integerList.get(1) && integerList.get(0) == integerList.get(2)
                && integerList.get(1) == integerList.get(2)) {
            integerList.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                int number = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
                integerList.add(number);
            }
        }
        return integerList;
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getJackpotList() {
        ArrayList<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        integerList.add(5);
        integerList.add(5);
        integerList.add(5);
        return integerList;
    }
}
```

If the result is, for example, `[4,4,4]`, the `for` loop generates new numbers. Yet it is still able to output 3 of the same integers. Why?

Comment: @Eran That's my mistake. I've changed "all unique" to "not all the same" to reflect the original description better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a nested loop. Your for loop should repeat until 3 acceptable numbers are found. I used an array to make the code more compact, but the same can be done with `ArrayList`.

```
public List<Integer> getNormalList() {
    Random r = new Random();
    int[] arr = new int[3]; // initialized to 0s by default
    int Low = 0;
    int High = 6;
    while (arr[0] == arr[1] && arr[1] == arr[2]) { // will repeat as long as the 3 number as
                                                   // all equal
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
        }
    }
    return Arrays.asList(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code fails because if it generates a list of duplicates, it just clears it and generates a new list, *without checking if the new list contains duplicates*. Here's my suggested alternate solution:

```
do {
    List<Integer> result = ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(0, 6).limit(3).boxed().collect(toList())
} while (result.get(0) == result.get(1) && result.get(0) == result.get(2))
return result;
```